# getting current text color of an item selected in listview

Tags: android, listview, textcolor

i want to get the currant text color of item selected in listview and then code accordingly.Can anybody please help me

```
  fieldlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            informationType = fieldlist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find text color using **getCurrentTextColor()**

for ex:-

```
textviewname.getCurrentTextColor();
```

Comment: how do i get it in OnitemClick Listener as above

Comment: what component you use in listview row? it depends on that but can try with view.getCurrentTextColor(); ?

Comment: its a textview inside listview

Comment: then you can use int textcolor = view.getCurrentTextColor(); and print log for more understanding.

Comment: can I do it in onItemClick?

Answer (score 0):

The first I suggest you use RecyclerView instead of ListView. But in case of ListView you can do this way below to get current text color.

In your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Your logic to getView

   convertView.setTag(yourTextView.getCurrentTextColor();)
   return convertView;
}
```

Then in OnitemClickListener

```
fieldlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        informationType = fieldlist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().replace(" ", "");
        int currentTextColor = view.getTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: int currentTextColor = view.getTag(); shows a red line below it saying required int found Object

Comment: Yep, I have just code with logic, not syntax here. getTag() return an Object. And you need to cast object to int/Integer/String/... whatever you want.

Comment: I got a color code 16711936.How do I check what color is it?

Comment: That's color, I don't understand why you need to check anymore. For example you call Color.Red() then return the color code like that. That is the result of getCurrentTextColor() method. If you want to compare just using if(currentTextColor == Color.yourColorYouWant)

Comment: I want Color.Green.How do I check if this color code belongs to that color?

Answer (score 0):

Update

1. Create one Interface as below, you can create it as a seperate class or as part of your activity/ fragment.

`public class ListItemClickNotifier {
    void onListItemClick(int colorCode);
}`

2. Implement this interface in your fragment/ activity class like this.

`ListItemClickNotifier listClickListener = new ListItemClickNotifier (

```
   @Override
   onListItemClick(int colorCode) {
    if (colorCode == Color.Green) {
       // Do your stuff here.
    }
});`
```

3. Pass this interface as object while initializing your adapter. Like below.

   `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, arraylist, listClickListener);`
4. Create a global object of ListItemClickListener in your adapter class and copy the passed object into it via constructor, As mentioned below.

`private ListItemClickNotifier mListClickListener;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList arrayList, ListItemClickNotifier listClickListener) {
          mListClickListener = listClickListener;

     }`

5. Create a click listener to your view in adapter in getView method like this.

   @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder holder = null;
       if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
       convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
       }
       convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {

   ```
   @Override
   public void Onclick(View view) {
                mListClickListener.onListItemClick(holder.textView.getCurrentTextColor());
   }
   });
   return convertView;
   }
   ```

Comment: the problem is that the textview is initialized inside the adapter while I want to fetch the color on onItemClickListener.If the color is Color.Green i want to code accordingly

Comment: Updated the answer as per your need. Code formatting is missed at some places please ignore that.

Comment: Instead of ItemClickListener your can use this, this will work same as your ItemclickListener.